# test the return value of function with parameter in bash/shell scripting without accessing $? or creating new variable

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to do the following in shell scripting:

```
if [ (is_number $arg1) -ne 0 ] || [ (is_number $arg2) -ne 0 ] ; then
    printf "Exit. Valid input must be positive integer.\n"
    return 1
fi
```

But it gave me syntax error. Do you have better solution? Thanks!

I want a solution without accessing `$?` or storing return value into variable, unless such answer doesn't exist.

I see you guys taking advantage of 0 and not 0. It make sense since 0 signify whether succeed or not.

Now, speaking it in a pure syntax way, I want to do the following:

```
if [ (is_number $arg1) -ne int ] || [ (is_number $arg2) -ne int] ; then
    printf "Exit. Valid input must be positive integer.\n"
    return 1
fi
```

Please provide a way, thanks.

Comment: `if ! is_number "$arg1" || ! is_number "$arg2"; then...`. See [Why is testing `$?` to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Comment: `[` is not part of `if` syntax; it's just another name for the command `test`. Don't use it unless you have a reason to use the `test` command.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you have better solution?

Call the actual functions.

```
is_number() { [[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; }
if ! is_number "$arg1" || ! is_number "$arg2"; then
```